# Deleting entities in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

This should be simple...

Im using the CRM web service to delete entities such as products -> service.Delete(product);

This sets the DeletionStateCode to 2 but when does it get deleted for real? I did this yesterday and they are still there...

Comment: You do mean deleting "records" not "entities" right?

Answer (score 6):

The Asynchronous Service (for CRM 4) or Deletion Service (for CRM 3) runs once a day and cleans up all these records from the database. If you need them cleaned up earlier than that, you can run the [Scale Group Job Editor](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ScaleGroupJobEditor) and set the deletion service to run in a few minutes.